# Small tile coloring app

Tags: python, game, random, tkinter

I made a small app that revolves around coloring tiles - I am a newby to Python so I am unsure whether I followed the general guidelines correct (use of functions and classes, format, syntax)

You can probably figure out the functionalities of the app if you test around a little :)

In order to run it, you need to paste the content of `https://pastebin.com/r4BhSYri` into `colors.txt` and change the path in line 10 - I didn't find a way to add something like a "script root folder" variable like in powershell yet.

(note that my original, first rough sketch was VERY messy, and this code includes a lot of improvements from a nice person, but i added a lot of stuff since then)

```
import tkinter as tk
import random


class ChangeColor(tk.Frame):

   def __init__(self, master):
       self.master = master
       tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
       txtfile = open("H:/Python/button_recolor_project/colors.txt", "r")
       self.__colors = txtfile.read().split(',')
       self.configure_gui()
       self.create_widgets()


   def configure_gui(self):
       self.input_button()
       self.wipe_button()
       self.input_textbox1()
       self.input_textbox2()
       self.output_textbox()
       root.title("Dancefloor")


   def input_button(self):
       self.configbutton = tk.Button(self.master)
       self.configbutton.grid(row = 6, column = 6,sticky="S",rowspan = 2)
       self.configbutton.config(width = 5,height = 2)
       self.configbutton.config(text="Config!")
       self.configbutton.config(command=lambda:self.recolor_on_demand())

   def wipe_button(self):
       self.wipebutton = tk.Button(self.master)
       self.wipebutton.grid(row=0,column=6,sticky="N",rowspan = 2)
       self.wipebutton.config(width=5)
       self.wipebutton.config(text="Wipe!")
       self.wipebutton.config(command=lambda:self.wipe_all_buttons())

   def input_textbox1(self):
       self.inputbox = tk.Entry(self.master)
       self.inputbox.grid(row = 6, column = 4,sticky="NW")
       self.inputbox.config(width=12)

   def input_textbox2(self):
       self.inputbox2 = tk.Entry(self.master)
       self.inputbox2.grid(row = 6, column = 4,sticky="SW")
       self.inputbox2.config(width=12)

   def output_textbox(self):
       self.outputbox = tk.Text(self.master)
       self.outputbox.grid(row = 6, column = 0,sticky="W",columnspan=4)
       self.outputbox.config(width=39,height=2)

   def testint(self,buttoninput):
           try:
                int(buttoninput)
                return True
           except ValueError:
                return False

   def wipe_all_buttons(self):
        for c in range (1,26):
           self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)].config(bg="white")
        self.outputbox.delete("1.0",tk.END)
        self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Wiped the grid!")

   def recolor_on_demand(self):
       buttoninput = self.inputbox.get()
       colorinput = self.inputbox2.get()
       self.outputbox.delete("1.0",tk.END)
       if colorinput == "" and buttoninput == "":
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Please enter a color & a button number!")
       elif colorinput == "":
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Please enter a color!")
       elif buttoninput == "":
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Please enter a button number!")
       elif self.testint(buttoninput) == False and colorinput not in self.__colors:
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Enter an integer and a valid color!")
       elif self.testint(buttoninput) == False:
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Enter an integer for the button number!")
       elif colorinput not in self.__colors and int(buttoninput) not in range(1,26):
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Enter a valid color name and \nbutton number!")
       elif colorinput not in self.__colors:
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Invalid color!")
       elif int(buttoninput) not in range(1,26):
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Button does not exist!")
       elif colorinput in self.__colors and int(buttoninput) in range(1,26):
           self.buttons['button{}'.format(buttoninput)].config(bg=colorinput)
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Button" + str(buttoninput) + " " + "has the color" + " " + colorinput)
       else:
           self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Unexpected exception!")


   def create_widgets(self):
       self.create_buttons()

   def create_buttons(self):
       self.buttons = {}
       c = 1
       for i in range(5):
           for j in range(5):
               self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)] = tk.Button(self.master)
               self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)].grid(row=i, column=j)
               self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)].config(width=10, height=5,bg="white")
               self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)].config(command=self.change_button_color)
               self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)].config(text=c)
               c += 1

   def random_button(self):
       return random.choice(list(range(1,26)))

   def get_random_color(self):
       return random.choice(self.__colors)

   def change_button_color(self):
       randomcolor = self.get_random_color()
       randombutton = self.random_button()
       for z in range(0,1):
          self.buttons['button{}'.format(randombutton)].config(bg=randomcolor)
          self.outputbox.delete("1.0",tk.END)
          self.outputbox.insert("1.0","Button" + str(randombutton) + " " + "has the color" + " " + randomcolor)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = tk.Tk()
   main_app = ChangeColor(root)
   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: edit: the script uses a text file (colors.txt) that includes all colors that are supported. i couldnt find a way to use the script root yet :(  - this is the text: https://pastebin.com/r4BhSYri

Comment: You should [Edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/195625/edit) your question to add relevant information instead of adding it as a comment

Comment: "script root folder"
Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934806/how-can-i-find-scripts-directory-with-python

The question says how to get the current directory (i.e. the directory the terminal was in when it called the script) and the accepted answer says how to get the directory that the script itself is stored in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a newby, this code looks great.  Some things to make it better (in no particular order).

#### PEP8

You should consider formatting your code in accordance with [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  This is important when sharing code, as the consistent style makes it much easier for other programmers to read your code.  There are various tools available to assist in making the code pep8 compliant.  I use the [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) IDE which will show pep8 violations right in the editor.

#### super():

Instead of calling the parent class `init()` directly, consider using [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).

This:

```
tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.master)
```

would be:

```
super(ChangeColor, self).__init__(master)
```

#### Reduce boilerplate:

If you see the exact same code repeat many times, try and refactor to eliminate it.  Something like this:

```
self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)] = tk.Button(self.master)
self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)].grid(row=i, column=j)
self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)].config(width=10, height=5, bg="white")
self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)].config(command=self.change_button_color)
self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)].config(text=c)
```

can be:

```
button = self.buttons['button{}'.format(c)] = tk.Button(self.master)
button.grid(row=i, column=j)
button.config(width=10, height=5, bg="white")
button.config(command=self.change_button_color)
button.config(text=c)
```

This removes much extra text, making things easier to read, and it is also more performant.

#### Don't compare bools:

```
elif self.testint(buttoninput) == False:
```

Should be:

```
elif not self.testint(buttoninput):
```

#### The random module has a integer range function:

So this:

```
return random.choice(list(range(1, 26)))
```

Could be:

```
return random.randint(1, 25)
```

#### Use string formatting:

Constructing strings use string concatenation (`+`) is both non-performant, and harder to read.  Instead use one of Python's myriad string formatting methods

```
self.outputbox.insert("1.0", "Button" + str(randombutton) + " " + "has the color" + " " + randomcolor)
```

Could be:

```
self.outputbox.insert("1.0", "Button{} has the color {}".format(randombutton, randomcolor))
```